# Cordova: How can I pass actions from webview page to the cordova framework (and native)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, outsystems

In our company we use Outsystems as an development platform.
Outsystems supplies a Outsystems Now native app that functions as a browser with native functions for the device.

We only develop the webpages on the webserver. We have the sourcecodes from the Outsystems Now app so we can edit the framework.

Thanks to the sourcecode I see that it uses Cordova/Phonegap as interface.

What I want to create are actions from the webpage that triggers actions in the Outsystems Now (Cordova/Phonegap) application. For example, the logout button on the page closes the session but the Cordova webview isn't aware.

Anyone experience with Cordova/Phonegap to create such actions?

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, OutSystems Now is based on Cordova so you can easily create a plugin for it and this is well documented throughout the internet..
For the purpose of this answer, lets say I have create one plugin named `LogoutPlugin` and that the available method is `logout`.

As for the communication between the webapp and OutSystems Now application, you can try the following:

- Install OutSystems Now from forge - needed to connect you OutSystems Now mobile app to your environment.
- Install Now Plugin common from forge - needed to load the cordova javascript file from the OutSystems Now application.

Now you can:

1. On Service Studio, and in your application, add reference to "Now Plugin common
2. Add reference to HTTPRequestHandler/RunJavaScript
3. Create a webblock and drag, into it, the NativePluginLoader from Now Plugin commons and a button.

   - Change the button method to ajax submit and create a new Screen Action, I called mine "Logout"
4. Open the "Logout" screen action and drag RunJavaScript action into it. This will be where we'll call the cordova plugin that we want! Since, in the beginning of this answer, I said I created LogoutPlugin, we would call it like so:

   `cordova.exec(function(){console.log("success");}, function(e){console.log("fail" + e);}, "LogoutPlugin", "logOut", []);`

On the native side, for example for Android, the plugin class would look something like the following:

```
public class LogoutPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        if (action.equals("logout"))
            logout();
        return true;
    }

    private void logout() {
        cordova.getActivity().finish();
    }   
}
```

Note: `cordova` will only be available if you're running the webapp inside OutSystems Now, otherwise the `NativePluginLoader` won't be able to load the cordova.js file from the device.

For further learning, you could take a look at OutSystems github repos where you could find some addons for OutSystems Now..

Hopefully this will get you going and also, [here's an oml as an example](http://www.filedropper.com/demoplugin)

Comment: @ρss You're absolutely right! updated answer with more informations